# determine if ajax call fails in .always function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make a condition which states: if ajax call fails or if the response text = `false`, do one thing `else` do something else. What I have come up with works in chrome, but it seems a bit rough and I'm not sure it will work in all browsers. Any suggestions on a better method would be much appreciated. Thanks for reading.

```
$.get('/check_session.php').always(function(data){  

 if(data == "[object Object]" || data == false){
    console.log('fail');
  }else{
    console.log('success')
  }
});
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can run "always" with more parameters, including the status code. If that is anything but 200, your request failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
$.get("/check_session.php").always(function (data, status) {
    if(status != "success" || data == false) {
        console.log("fail");
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }

});
```